# has fsolve been replaced in MATLAB 2010a?

Tags: matlab

I just upgraded to MATLAB 2010a.  It seems that fsolve no longer works.  Has this been replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [FSOLVE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fsolve.html) is a part of the [Optimization Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization/). Do you still have access to this toolbox with your new MATLAB version? Here are some things you can try to find out:

- Can you use any of [the other functions in the toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/optim/ug/bqnk0r0.html)?
- What does the output of the function [VER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ver.html) show you? Does the Optimization Toolbox show up?
- Use the function [LICENSE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/license.html) and see if either of these returns 1:

  ```
  license('test','Optimization_Toolbox')      %# See if a license exists
  license('checkout','Optimization_Toolbox')  %# Try to check a license out
  ```

Comment: huh, my opimization license shows up.  I think we have the license but didn't install it.